# Running both Audio Queue Services and AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

I'm creating an App where I need to record video+audio as a movie but I need to process the audio at the same time with Audio Queue Services.

My issue is that when I run `AudioQueueStart()`, my AVCaptureSession is interrupted and I no longer receive samples from

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Any suggestion ?